# View + Left Join returning error 1054 in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, sql, view, firebird

I'm writting a view in MySQL 5.5. My code is the one below:

```
  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_lancamentos;
  CREATE VIEW vw_lancamentos AS
  SELECT
    l.id,
    l.data_hora_lancamento,
    l.valor,
    l.descricao,
    l.veiculo_id,
    l.plano_conta_id,
    pc.id,
    pc.master_id,
    pc.descricao,
    pc.tipo_movimento
  FROM
    lancamentos l, plano_de_contas pc
  LEFT JOIN
    plano_de_contas on (l.plano_conta_id = pc.id);
```

When I try to compile this code above, the server returns this error:
**Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'l.plano_conta_id' in 'on clause'**

How can I make it work? I worked with Firebird before, and as I can see it's quite different from MySQL.

Comment: Wow. I didn't understood what yo u told me. Sorry ._.

Comment: That query syntax wouldn't have worked in Firebird either.

Comment: Of course this won't work on Firebird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `JOIN` syntax is wrong and you have two columns with the same name. If you want to return both `l.id` and `pc.id` then you will want to give an alias to both of those fields that distinguishes them:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_lancamentos AS
  SELECT
    l.id as l_id,  --  add alias
    l.data_hora_lancamento,
    l.valor,
    l.descricao,
    l.veiculo_id,
    l.plano_conta_id,
    pc.id as pc_id, --  add alias
    pc.master_id,
    pc.descricao,
    pc.tipo_movimento
  FROM lancamentos l
  LEFT JOIN plano_de_contas pc
     on l.plano_conta_id = pc.id;
```

Comment: You don't need an alias on both, but you are better off providing one on both so you know which table the record is coming from. The `plano_conta_id` is a different name so there will be no confusion with that column.  It is the two fields named `id` that is the issue.

Comment: It's still showing the error **1054** telling that it don't know the column in the line `pc.id as pc_id, --  add alias`

Comment: @JuninhoDG see my edit, it should be fixed now. That was my fault, when I rewrote it I missed the `pc` alias on the table.

Comment: @bluefeet, I just added aliases to the fields **descricao** and it worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well according to this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fd33/1) it's sufficient by giving the alias to one id as OP didn't mention what sort of a data type either of the ID fields holds. So it's not really necessary with your reasoning though.. :)

Comment: @bonCodigo I am not saying it is required.  I am saying that at least my preference would be to alias both fields. If you alias both, then you automatically know in the result what table the data is coming from.

Comment: Thanks. At least it made me do the fiddle to confirm :) In terms of clarity in the presenation, it's easier to have different alias.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this...sorry igonore my comment, I just noticed how you are doing the `LEFT JOIN`. The way arrange the join Syntax is wrong...

```
....

 FROM lancamentos l
 LEFT JOIN
 plano_de_contas pc on (l.plano_conta_id = pc.id);
```

EDIT AS PER OP'S COMMENT:

in your select query you are selecting thtese...both the same... so to recorrect the reasoning, you need to add alias to one.

```
    l.id,
    pc.id as pcid,
```

EDIT:

- **[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fd33/1)** : it's sufficient to provide alias to one column out of the two that has the same name/duplicate name...

Comment: Hi man. Now the server is showing me this: **Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'id'**